# What does "no modification but copy created from here" mean?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN for the version control on my project. I have been working in a branch of my repository without trouble. Then I tried to create a sub-branch of my working branch (i.e. project_repository/branches/original_branch/sub_branch). That created a directory for my sub-branch in the original branch's folder structure. (Oops. I'll never try that again.) When I realized that I didn't want that directory I used SVN Delete to remove it from the branch. Now, whenever I look at the revision graph of my project, it shows a node in the sub-branch that says that it was deleted. But after that node, it shows a copy of the HEAD node of the original branch. When I hover my mouse over that node instead of "modified" or "deleted" it says "no modification but copy created from here." What does that mean? Why is that node there?

Incidentally, if I chose the option to hide deleted branches, I don't see the sub-branch or the "phantom node." I just want to make sure that I haven't done any permanent damage to my repository and I'd like this odd behavior to end if possible.

Here's a screen-shot of my revision graph:

[alt text http://img67.imageshack.us/img67/7462/phantomsvnnode.png](http://img67.imageshack.us/img67/7462/phantomsvnnode.png)

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to merge this branch to trunk if it go then revert changes and live with it. Some svnadmin hackers can help You with deleting that commit bit if merge will go, live with it :)

Comment: After I posted this I switched from SVN to Mercurial for version control. Before I did, though, I decided to ignore this message. Nothing bad or weird ever happened, so I did decide to just "live with it", as you say. Thanks.